# Using Quarto and Github Pages to start my Python Blog

Tags: git, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, github-pages, quarto

I am a little confused how to start my blog with Quarto to Github Pages, somehow nothing works as described. Unfortunately almost all tutorials are with RStudio and I would like to publish files from Jupyter. The Github Page I try to use is located here:
https://github.com/MkengineTA/MkengineTA.github.io.
My settings are "Deploy from branch", "main" and "/docs"

Here is what I have done so far. I have a folder "myblog" with the following files:

- _quarto.yml
- blog.qmd
- index.qmd
- profile.jpg
- style.css

Here's what my _quarto.yml says:

```
project:
  type: website
  output-dir: docs
    
website:
  title: "Tobias Averbeck"
  description: "Tobias Averbeck's Blog."
  navbar:
    right:
      - text: Blog
        href: blog.qmd
      - icon: github
        href: https://github.com/MkengineTA
      - icon: twitter
        href: https://twitter.com
format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo
    css: styles.css
```

With quarto render Day1.ipynb I now also have an html document, but I don't know where to put it all on Github.

I looked at this tutorial: https://quarto.org/docs/publishing/github-pages.html#render-to-docs

The first option says something about a docs folder, but I can't find that anywhere on my end either, it was never created.
Other than that, this page also just says to *git push* after *quarto render*, where I get the following message:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

And that's where the tutorial for publishing via docs ends.
I've watched many youtube videos (unfortunately all with Rstudio) and read tutorials, but I just can't get it to work. I hope someone here has a clue about this, otherwise I would also use alternatives to Quarto if anyone has suggestions.

Comment: At the very first, you need to make sure that the website folder is a [local git repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository). From the error, it seems you are not in a git repository.

Comment: Okay, I put my Day1.ipynb file in the following folder: "C:\Github\MkengineTA.github.io" then I used "quarto render Day1.ipynb", which said:

pandoc
  to: html
  output-file: Day1.html
  standalone: true
  section-divs: true
  html-math-method: mathjax
  wrap: none
  default-image-extension: png

metadata
  document-css: false
  link-citations: true
  date-format: long
  lang: en
  title: Day 1
  author: Tobias Averbeck
  date: 'March 5th, 2023'
  jupyter: python3

Output created: Day1.html

Then git push: Everything up-to-date
But my repo is still empty

Comment: But I have Github Desktop, can I use that as well?